# unable to join two tables rows by name MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join the tables and get an output
I am matching by "name"

I have 2 Tables **api_log_2** and **api_security_2**

```
TABLE 1 = api_log_2
----------------------------------
|id    |name        |email       |
---------------------------------
|101   |john test   |j@gm.io     |
|102   |gary rest   |g@gm.io     |
|102   |megh west   |m@gm.io     |
----------------------------------

TABLE 2 = api_security_2
----------------------------------
|vt    |name        |ipn         |
----------------------------------
|x12   |john test   |1245774     |
|e34   |gary rest   |2145876     |
|h76   |megh west   |9245228     |
----------------------------------
```

my SQL query

```
SELECT
  api_log_2.id,
  api_security_2.vt,
  api_security_2.name,
  api_security_2.ipn,
  api_log_2.email
 
FROM
 api_log_2,
 api_security_2
WHERE
 api_log_2.name = api_security_2.name
 AND 
 api_security_2.name = 'john test';
```

Now, the problem is when I am running this query I am not getting result.

Edited: I have a space between name

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `SELECT name, HEX(name) FROM api_security_2` and `SELECT name, HEX(name) FROM api_log_2` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using proper JOINs helps you get your wanted result.

also aliases help, to type less.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE api_log_2 (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `name` VARCHAR(4),
>   `email` VARCHAR(7)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO api_log_2
>   (`id`, `name`, `email`)
> VALUES
>   ('101', 'john', 'j@gm.io'),
>   ('102', 'gary', 'g@gm.io'),
>   ('102', 'megh', 'm@gm.io');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE api_security_2 (
>   `vt` VARCHAR(3),
>   `name` VARCHAR(4),
>   `ipn` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO api_security_2
>   (`vt`, `name`, `ipn`)
> VALUES
>   ('x12', 'john', '1245774'),
>   ('e34', 'gary', '2145876'),
>   ('h76', 'megh', '9245228');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>  al.id,
>  ase.vt,
>  ase.name,
>  ase.ipn,
>  al.email
>  
> FROM
>  api_log_2 al INNER JOIN 
>  api_security_2 ase  ON  al.name = ase.name
>  WHERE
>  ase.name = 'john';
> ```
>
> ```
>  id | vt  | name |     ipn | email  
> --: | :-- | :--- | ------: | :------
> 101 | x12 | john | 1245774 | j@gm.io
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=213b7297eea0a73d3b80fd8238d1b8d4)*

> ```
> CREATE TABLE api_log_2 (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `name` VARCHAR(200),
>   `email` VARCHAR(7)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO api_log_2
>   (`id`, `name`, `email`)
> VALUES
>   ('101', 'john test', 'j@gm.io'),
>   ('102', 'gary rest', 'g@gm.io'),
>   ('102', 'megh west', 'm@gm.io');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE api_security_2 (
>   `vt` VARCHAR(3),
>   `name` VARCHAR(200),
>   `ipn` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO api_security_2
>   (`vt`, `name`, `ipn`)
> VALUES
>   ('x12', 'john test', '1245774'),
>   ('e34', 'gary rest', '2145876'),
>   ('h76', 'megh west', '9245228');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>  al.id,
>  ase.vt,
>  ase.name,
>  ase.ipn,
>  al.email
>  
> FROM
>  api_log_2 al INNER JOIN 
>  api_security_2 ase  ON  al.name = ase.name
>  WHERE
>  ase.name = 'john test';
> ```
>
> ```
>  id | vt  | name      |     ipn | email  
> --: | :-- | :-------- | ------: | :------
> 101 | x12 | john test | 1245774 | j@gm.io
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=478b2797813749ea599453019cc066c9)*

Comment: Thanks. It works on name with no space.
I have a name here as "John  test"
now, when i use `ase.name = 'John test';`
it doesn't throw any result

Comment: It is no problem of the space https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0b09a4ad1bbc157c4b715e5e5080de3b  the equal means they have to be3 exqactly equal on all positions,tbales an where clause

Comment: Proper joins (while always the right way to go) make no difference in this instance.https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a6c7b2370a2961bb01c88ec1123bde78